# How to get instance of ActivityManager in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

To check if the application is in foregraound or background i am trying to access ActivityManager as per below.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = GetSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager;
            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            foreach(RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess in appProcesses){
                if(appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
                    Log.i("Foreground App", appProcess.processName);
                    //SetNotification ();
                }
            }
```

But I am getting compliation error as "Android.Content.Context does not contain a definition for ACTIVITY_SERVICE" at first line.

How can i access ActivityManager in Xamarin ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change from

```
ActivityManager activityManager = GetSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager;
```

to

```
ActivityManager activityManager = GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService) as ActivityManager;
```

To get instance of `ActivityManager`.